# Symfony2 concept : Bundle abstraction with bilateral relations

Tags: symfony, entities

we are currently building a kind of website framework based on symfony2.

as customer needs differs from each other, i would like to be able to remove certains bundle according to customer demands without rewriting relations .

My main issue is bundles have bilateral relation ship between them.

for example :

- Optional bundle entity ( named A )
- Second optional bundle entity ( named C )
- Core bundle entity ( named B )

  A <-> B Bilateral relationship.

  A -> C  Unilateral relationship

  C -< B  Unliateral relationship

I think the solution would be to abstract theses entities relations with inner entities  bundle that would override the targetted entities ( which i could get trough a config.yml parameter )  but i m not sure that would be the most efficient solution.

any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand the question but this might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: i m looking for making optional relationship between different entities from different bundle, that way bundles should be independant from each other

Comment: you link seems to fits what i m looking for, you should write an answer that i ll mark as answer in order to clean the question